# How to convert data into Result<Record> data type in jooq

Tags: java, jooq

I am working on a large project in which the functions I want to use, accept data in the form of List< Result< Record >> and then send it to frontend or convert to csv.

I am receiving data in the form of List< Object > and I want to convert data from List< Object > to List< Result< Record >>. How to do it?

```
public class Object {
  int x;
  string str;
  float f;
}
```

Comment: For the record, this question was asked also on the issue tracker: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12552

Answer (score 0):

You can create in-memory `Result` values using [`DSLContext.newResult()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newResult(org.jooq.Field...)) and [`DSLContext.newRecord()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord(org.jooq.Field...)) like this:

```java
Field<Integer> x = ...;
Field<String> str = ...;
Field<Float> f = ...;

Result<Record3<Integer, String, Float>> r = ctx.newResult(x, str, f);
for (Object o : list)
    r.add(ctx.newRecord(x, str, f).values(o.x, o.str, o.f));
```